# Sending Image from Android to RestFul webservice

Tags: android, rest

My Android code is following ,i want to send the image file from Android App to my restful webserivce, code for the Android App and WebService with Error given below

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String iFileName = "abc.jpg";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        String Tag = "fSnd";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        try {
            //  Log.e(Tag,"Starting Http File Sending to URL");

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL



            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

           conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-    data;boundary=" + boundary);

            conn.setRequestProperty("file", iFileName);

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";file=\""
                    + URLEncoder.encode(iFileName, "UTF-8") +"\""+ lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // close streams
            fileInputStream.close();

            dos.flush();

            //      Log.e(Tag,"File Sent, Response: "+String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
            System.out.println("File Sent, Response: "+String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            // retrieve the response from server
            int ch;

            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                b.append((char) ch);
            }
            String s = b.toString();
            //  Log.i("Response",s);
            System.out.println("Response : "+s);

            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            // Log.e(Tag, "URL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            System.out.println("URL error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Log.e(Tag, "IO error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            System.out.println("IO error: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

on the RestFul webservice side i am using following code...

```
@POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
        System.out.println("File download starts now");
        String uploadedFileLocation = "d://uploaded/" + fileDetail.getFileName();

        System.out.println("Testing for file download");
        // save it
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

but i am getting following error on webservice side...
Apr 13, 2017 3:29:11 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, and MIME media type multipart/form-data was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy

Kindly check my code...and guide me how to resolve the issue...
```

Comment: Are you using retrofit for networking?

Comment: i am using jersey

Comment: I am talking in terms of android, what are you using on client (android)

Comment: There is something wrong with your headers, you should consider switching to Retrofit since it handles all of that fancy stuff for you (lie threading - async task are realy bad), and its supper easy to use

Comment: the error is relating to
@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

and the data send from Android...it is not relating to threads...
i couldn't figure it out what type of data or content type is missing...